# Easy way to tell 12awg from 14awg metal clad?

Tags: electrical, wiring

My house was built in 1940 and all original wiring is metal clad / BX cable.  With Romex, yellow vs white can tell me wire gauge.  Is there any similar tell for MC?  I suspect it's all 12 awg but I'd like to double check, only thing I know to do is use calipers to measure diameter of the conductor.
Thanks

Comment: Even if there was a way to tell by measuring the outer diameter of the armored cable, that would be easier then prying open gangboxes and tearing apart old wiring to measure a conductor.

Comment: Found this guide: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.encorewire.com/wp-content/uploads/EncoreWire-XHHW-MC_AL.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiu85WR5MbjAhXCxFkKHbH4C3cQ6sMDMAd6BAgCEAY&usg=AOvVaw1BqV4KnLAd0XjVSeSpkvdV But all mine is dirt-grey. Can I trust those OD's?

Comment: Can you get some calipers on stripped wire ends (with the power off?) Also, is it old-style BX (no bonding strip), new style AC (skinny bonding strip), or MC (no bonding strip, with a separate green wire for grounding)?

Comment: Never knew the difference.  It is old style BX, no bonding strip.  I can get calipers on it if I absolutely must.  Sounds like there's no easy identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a piece of #12 scrap wire and compare it to what you have. If the wire is the same it is 12, If the wire is larger usually #10 if smaller #14 other than an electric range # 14,12 & 10 will be everything except  the range it will be much larger. These are the sizes used in a 1940’s era homes for the most part.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a hard time visually comparing the wires, go buy a standard, cheap light switch or outlet that has a back-stab connection (the insert spring clamp kind, not the screw down kind).

These connectors are normally labeled "14GA ONLY" and are designed to only fit 14GA wire.  A strand of 12GA will not fit in the hole.  Even with poor lighting this should be a simple, foolproof way to identify 14GA and 12GA wire.